# Laravel use blade directive inside php block

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel 5.7, I created a Blade directive :

```
// create blade direct for prices
Blade::directive('price', function ($money) {
    return "<?php echo number_format($money, 2, ',', ' ') .' €'; ?>";
});
```

I can use it in my blade templates, like this :

```
<span>@price($product->price)</span>
```

But how can I use it in php approach ? I have this code :

```
@include('emails.table', [
     __('order.reference') => $order->reference,
     __('order.total') => @price($order->total),
])
```

But it doesn't work :

> Call to undefined function price()

I tried without *@* but no success. Must I use a kind of php helper for that ?

Comment: Why are you translating the names of the variables you are passing to the subview?

Comment: You mean it's better to translate in the subview and pass only the key ?

Comment: Indeed, I have added an answer where I did just that.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the variable through to the view and use the `@price` blade directive in that view.

```
@include('emails.table', [
     'reference' => $order->reference,
     'total' => $order->total,
])
```

And in `emails.table` you do the following:

```
<div>@trans('order.total'): @price($total)</div>
```

Comment: Yes but my subview is very generic, I only loop through all elements and display the value